# Does iTextSharp support Windows Metro Apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, pdf, itext, microsoft-metro

Does iTextSharp support Windows Metro Apps?

I am trying to create PDFs from a C# Metro App, but PdfWriter.GetInstance requires some arguments which is not available in WinRT.

Any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any arguments what would not be available in WinRT, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missing an using or dll reference at the beginning of your program, try to use the full namespaces... I do not see any reasons why ITextSharp should not work in a MetroApp.

Comment: I have added this namespaces

using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

and I am following this article

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same iTextSharp version as in the article. There are some changes in the arguments of the methods over diffrent version iTextSharp.

Comment: I am using v5.3.0.0, downloaded from the link given in that article

Comment: v5.3 was not availble at the time of publication of the article, so try an earlier version of iTextSharp: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/

Comment: article was posted on 12 October 2008, but available older iTextSharp is of 8 December, 2009
so please can you help me by providing any code snippet or sample ?